# Select Option Unable To Show Up In Other rows

Tags: php, html, html-select

I have this particular code in a `<table>`. The `Select Option` only show display details and other options to choose in the first row and not the others.

From the image, the data saved in the database only appears on row 1 `Select Option` but not the other row.

[image]

Code is over here:

```
  <table class="table table-striped table-hover ">
           <thead>
                <tr>
                   <th>Staff Name</th>
                   <th>Current Role</th>
                   <th>Select Role</th>
                </tr>
           </thead>
           <?php
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($successStaffQuery)) {
                $staffId = $row['staff_id'];
                $staffName = $row['staff_name'];
                $staffRole = $row['role_type'];
            ?>
                 <tr>
                   <td><?php echo $staffName; ?></td>
                   <td><?php echo $staffRole; ?></td>
                   <td>
                        <div class="form-group">
                             <form action="doChangeRole.php" method="post" name="register">
                                 <input type="hidden" name="getStaffId" value="<?php echo $staffId ?>" >
                                 <div class="form-group">
                                 <select class="form-control" onchange="this.form.submit()" id="select" name="roleChange">
                                  <?php
                                      while ($role = mysqli_fetch_array($successRoleQuery)) {
                                        if ($row['role_id'] = $role['role_id']) {
                                            ?>
                                            <option value="<?php echo $role['role_id']; echo 'selected'; ?>"><?php echo $role['role_type']; ?></option>
                                  <?php
                                   }
                                        }
                                 ?>
                                 </select>
                       </div>
                         <noscript><input type="submit" value="Submit"></noscript>
                            </form>
                  </div>
                  </td>
              </tr>
                        <?php
                    }
                    ?>
   </table>
```

Based on what I understand, the data should be showing up but in this case the `select option` just stopped running after successfully display the options on the first row. Anyone can help?

Comment: it is because you are adding only one option to your select box.

Answer (score 0):

a lot of bugs in your code:

1. you add the option only, if the row role_id = role_id for $role
2. you do not compare, you assign $role['role_id'] to $row['role_id]
3. you output the selected tag into your value tag?

change your option code to following (remove the wrong if tag

```
//loop your success query
while ($role = mysqli_fetch_array($successRoleQuery)) {
    //output the options
    //add selected tag only to one option
    echo
        '<option value="'.$role['role_id'].'"'.($role['role_id'] == $row['role_id'] ? ' selected': '').'>'
            .$role['role_type']
        .'</option>';
};
```

code not tested!

Comment: tried your code, but still the same outcome as mine shown in the picture.